# How to keep the dom and scope on memory for the last seen page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm developing an hybrid mobile app using a SPA with angularjs, so I'm using routes to determine which page will be displayed and I'm using transitions (angular style, with ng-enter, ng-leave, etc) to change between pages.

However I'm having problem when users try to go back in the application. First of all, I can't use window.history.back because not always the last page seen is the page that the back button must lead on, so I have to change the route to the correct location.

Anyone is willing to wait a bit when clicking in a item that will lead to another page, but the opposite is not real. When users tap the back button and the app change the route, it takes some time to render the page as if it were a new page, but users keep tapping the back button because they feel like the app has stopped working.

I wanna know if there is a way to keep in memory the elements of the page that were already rendered to fasten the process of going back on the application.

P.S.: I know this way I will need a good memory consumption tracking to prevent memory leaks and a expensive usage that would make the application even slower.

Answer (score 0):

I guess ui.router with nested views should help you.
Please see example http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/42/item/b
(link blog & fax)
As you see, click on the links don't lead to reload all page (only required content) but urls are different for each views.

There's documentation for nested views
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views